# multiple price sets?

Tags: wordpress, price-sets

I need to use 2 price sets on a membership page. The first is for National membership and has several options, mostly concerning the publications delivered with the membership level. This National membership is required. The second price set is for local chapter membership and members could select none, one or several. Each local chapter has its own price.

This could look something like this:

National membership
 - email newsletter as pdf - $10
 - printed newsletter by post - $25
 - printed newsletter plus glossy magazine - $75

Local chapters
 - West - $15.00
 - Central - $25.00
 - East - $10.00
 - None - $0.00

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,
JWP

Answer (score 3):

The way we do it is to set up multiple price fields on one price set. The first price field you would make required, the second field wouldn't be required. Then people are required to select something from the first field, but then can choose what (if anything) they select from the second field.

We do it to have a required registration at the top, but then a textbook you can choose whether or not you purchase. You can have multiple items in each field, we just only have one in each.

[image]

Comment: Jenni - what you are suggesting is pretty much what I had figured out originally. But I haven't figured out how to get 2 price sets on a single contribution page. Thanks.

Comment: It's not two sets - it's multiple fields on a single set. Each field can have multiple options and you can have multiple fields on a single set.